# Find $\{a, b, c\} \in \Bbb{Z}$ that minimise $\left\|v_0 + a\cdot v_1 + b\cdot v_2 + c\cdot v_3 \right\|$ where $\{v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3\} \in \Bbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, lattices-in-lie-groups

I need find all pairwise shortest distance between any two atoms 3d tiled parallelepiped.
I can calculated the exact solution for where $\{a, b, c\} \in \Bbb{R}$ and considering all 8 rounding directions but I'm not sure that would be correct.

Comment: $a,b,c \in \mathbb N \ \text{or} \ \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: In fact, if $a,b,c$ are real numbers, do you agree that the minimum will be $0$ ?

Comment: $a, b, c \in \Bbb{N}$ and yes, if they are real, the minimum is always $0$ if $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent.

Comment: You say that the coefficients $a,b,c$ are integers : therefore you **haven't** a minimum equal to $0$ in general.

Comment: I was trying to agree with you that *if* they were real I would be able to solve the problem by using a change of basis.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for improving the readability of the question? I'm new to asking questions on mathematics.

Comment: Therefore, is it  $\mathbb N$ (giving a lattice occupying a kind of octant) or  $\mathbb Z$ (the whole space) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131966/discussion-between-charles-beattie-and-jean-marie).

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer.

Let us work in a 2D framework where the ideas can be more easily expressed.

Let us consider the exact decomposition of $-v_0$ (the sign is important) with coefficients $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$-v_0=Av_1+Bv_2$$

(we assume $\{v_1,v_2 \}$ independent).

Now consider the lattice generated by all the $av_1+bv_2$ ($a,b \in \mathbb Z$), i.e., the set of parallelograms:

$$P_{pq}=\{av_1+bv_2 | p \le a \le p+1, q \le b \le q+1\}\tag{1}$$

At least one of them contains $-v_0$.

The first idea is to consider points

$$pv_1+qv_2, \ \ pv_1+(q+1)v_2, \ \ (p+1)v_1+qv_2, \ \ (p+1)v_1+(q+1)v_2, \tag{2}$$

**But** the prospection cannot be reduced to these 4 vertices as shown on the following counterexample :

[image]

*Fig. : $F$ is the closest lattice point to $G$ though it is not one of the 4 vertices of the parallelogram countaining $G$!*

A first answer is to propect for closest points along the strips containing this parallelogram (for example the gridpoints situated on the border of the strip between lines $FC$ and $EB$ and/or on the border of the strip between $EF$ and $BC$).

(Of course, for you it will be slabs in 3D).

A better idea, so I think, is not to abandon what has been said for (2) but after a [change of basis] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_reduction) for the lattice. Indeed, the problem in the counterexample I just gave is that the parallelograms are very elongated/slanted. Had we taken another equivalent basis (for example $v'_1=v_1;v'_2=v_1-v_2$ with determinant $\pm 1$, important), less "slanted" we would hopefully make rarer or impossible such counterexamples.

Comment: In fact, there exists so-called [lattice reduction algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_reduction) making the basis "skewness" the less important possible.

Comment: Many thanks, I will take a look.

Comment: I'm going to consider all parallelepipeds that have an AABB (axis aligned bounding box) that contain $v$. This can be done by finding the first parallelepiped analytically then walking in each direction until the AABB not longer contains $v$.